# Fitted vs observed plot with line from glmer model

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, lme4

I have a data frame that is made up individuals in different treatment groups, with a 1 for if they survived and a 0 for if they are dead, and a 3rd column indicating which dish. I ran a glmer model using lme4 package with Dish_ID as my random variable. I have a piece of code from base plot which plots the mortality rate against treatment group using the line from my glmer model. How can I write the same observed vs fitted plots in ggplot. I have tried looking online but cant seem to find an answer that explains the process.

I want to get the line from my binomial model (manually not using geom_smooth) and then plot my observed points in red in ggplot2. Thanks for the help.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)

mortality_data$Dish_ID <- as.factor(mortality_data$Dish_ID)
mortality_model <- glmer(Survived ~ Treatment + (1|Dish_ID), data = mortality_data, family = "binomial")
summary(mortality_model) 

plot(mortality_data$Treatment, 1 - fitted(mortality_model), ylim = c(0,1))
plot(mortality_data$Treatment, 1 - fitted(mortality_model), ylim = c(0,1), type = "l", xlab = "Concentration of Cu2SO4", ylab = "Mortality rate")
tv <- unique(mortality_data$Treatment)
#observed in red
for (i in tv) {
  points(i, y = 1 - mean(mortality_data$Survived[mortality_data$Treatment == i]), col = "red")
}
```

my data frame looks something like this if it is of any use. There are 540 individuals, 90 for each treatment group

| Treatment | Survived | Dish_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.05 | 1 | Dish_1 |
| 0.04 | 0 | Dish_3 |

Comment: `plot()` is usually a base plotting function although it’s generic so I suppose some package might define a ggplot compatible fun by that name.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg